# Any other studied psychological phenomena like reactance?

Tags: video-games

Consider the following situations

- You are walking along a narrow ledge overlooking a void.  You know you should not look down but .. you do
- You have an annoying little morsel of food stuck between your teeth.  You know very well that trying to prise it loose with your tongue is a futile effort.  But you still do it...

I am in the process of putting the finishing touches to a game where the natural tendency of the player to perform actions that will result in scoring points will in fact result in a smaller win.  Everything in the game play push the player to force an early win with a low score.

I would like to review any studies of such phenomena in psychology so I can leverage a more value into the overall player experience.  Reactance comes close to describing what the player is naturally pushed to do but not quite... .  Are there any other effects of the same ilk that might come closer?  If so, are there any good studies of what drives/amplifies these effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to look at [Steindl, et al. (2015)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1027/2151-2604/a000222).

This paper presents an overview of research into Reactance that has been done since Miron and Brehm's 40 years review ([2006](https://doi.org/10.1024/0044-3514.37.1.9)) of all research since Brehm first proposed reactance theory (1966).

### References

Brehm J. W. (1966). *A theory of psychological reactance*. New York, NY: Academic Press.

Miron A. M. & Brehm J. W. (2006). Reactance theory – 40 years later. *Zeitschrift Für Sozialpsychologie/Journal of Social Psychology, 37*(1), 9-18. https://doi.org/10.1024/0044-3514.37.1.9

Steindl, C., Jonas, E., Sittenthaler, S., Traut-Mattausch, E., & Greenberg, J. L. (2015). Understanding psychological reactance: New developments and findings. *Zeitschrift fur Psychologie/Journal of Psychology, 223*(4), 205-214.
https://doi.org/10.1027/2151-2604/a000222